# Trying to draw lines that connect two points using PIL ImageDraw.Draw.line()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get a skeleton using [Movenet](https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/blob/master/examples/movenet_pose_estimation.py). For pose detection, it is inferencing the joints and afterwards drawing ellipses using PIL wherever there are joints

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from pycoral.adapters import common
from pycoral.utils.edgetpu import make_interpreter

_NUM_KEYPOINTS = 17

  interpreter = make_interpreter(args.model)
  interpreter.allocate_tensors()

  img = Image.open(args.input)
  resized_img = img.resize(common.input_size(interpreter), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  common.set_input(interpreter, resized_img)
  #common.set_input(interpreter, img)

  interpreter.invoke()

  pose = common.output_tensor(interpreter, 0).copy().reshape(_NUM_KEYPOINTS, 3)
  print(pose)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
  width, height = img.size
  for i in range(0, _NUM_KEYPOINTS):
    draw.ellipse(
        xy=[
            pose[i][1] * width - 2, pose[i][0] * height - 2,
            pose[i][1] * width + 2, pose[i][0] * height + 2
        ],
        fill=(255, 0, 0))
  img.save(args.output)
  print('Done. Results saved at', args.output)
```

As you can see from this [sample image](https://www.freepik.es/psd-premium/hombre-joven-loco-pose-bailar_2370009.htm), the skeleton tracking (the joints detected) inference is fine.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Just to have a more visual output, I wanted to draw the lines between the respective points. I know which points [should connect to which](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/pose_estimation/overview#how_it_works). Drawing the lines does not alter the final img result at all... And I can't see why.

```
for i in range(0, _NUM_KEYPOINTS):
                draw.ellipse(
                    xy=[
                        pose[i][1] * width - 2, pose[i][0] * height - 2,
                        pose[i][1] * width + 2, pose[i][0] * height + 2
                    ],
                    fill=(255, 0, 0))
draw.line([(pose[7][1], pose[7][0]),(pose[5][1], pose[5,0])], fill = 'red', width=3)
draw.line([(pose[9][1], pose[9][0]),(pose[7][1], pose[7,0])], fill = 'red', width=3)
```

I think I can do it with numpy and matplotlib (being the inference format a `numpy.ndarray`), but I wanted to stick to PIL as it is how it is done in this example. This is the output of `pose` in   `pose = common.output_tensor(interpreter, 0).copy().reshape(_NUM_KEYPOINTS, 3)`

```
[[0.2581018  0.5776564  0.70056206]
 [0.24990809 0.6022375  0.6350124 ]
 [0.22532697 0.5776564  0.49981618]
 [0.27039236 0.589947   0.43016967]
 [0.20893955 0.53259104 0.5694627 ]
 [0.32365146 0.6063344  0.15568045]
 [0.2949735  0.41378227 0.24581124]
 [0.44655707 0.67188406 0.6350124 ]
 [0.4178791  0.34413573 0.84395194]
 [0.36462    0.7456274  0.75382113]
 [0.32365146 0.31545776 0.36462   ]
 [0.5407847  0.58175325 0.6350124 ]
 [0.5448816  0.4547508  0.6350124 ]
 [0.70056206 0.68827146 0.6350124 ]
 [0.70875573 0.4793319  0.6350124 ]
 [0.8521456  0.6513998  0.84395194]
 [0.8685331  0.4711382  0.70056206]]
```

Comment: when you draw points you do `* width` `* height` but when you draw lines then you forgot `* width` `* height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw points you use `* width` `* height` to recalculate positions.

But when you draw lines then you forgot `* width` `* height`

```
draw.line(
    [(pose[7][1] * width, pose[7][0] * height), 
     (pose[5][1] * width, pose[5][0] * height)], 
    fill='red', width=3)
```

Comment: I was missing that part, I had some sort of tunnel vision and could not notice that. Thank you so much. Lines are getting drawn a bit randomly for some reason (not in the points of ellipses) but that's a matter of working it out. Thank you so much!